# Parse html page and get value using css selector in golang

Tags: go

I want to parse value of particular div of HTML.Eg.I have class like **"funcname"** so can i parse value at this div in golang?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [the github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery package](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery). If you're familar with jQuery selectors, it won't be a problem for you.

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(contents)
// handle err
doc.Find(".funcname")
```

Comment: There is any way to do this without using any goquery package